# UpperCase Hostname in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Good morning.
I have a problem to UpperCase the name of a file with the hostname. I'm trying to configure with this:

```
<Property name="example">$$upper{${hostName}}</Property>
...
<RollingFile name="RA.FileAppender" fileName="${example}_%d{yyMMdd}.log" filePattern="${example}_%d{yyMMdd}_%02i.log.gz">
```

But this doesn't work. This is the name of file

$$upper{RealHostName}_%d{yyMMdd}.log

How can does this work?
Thanks and regards

Comment: Did you try `${upper:${hostName}}`?

Comment: Yes, same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this works!

```
<Property name="example">Logs_${upper:${hostName}}_${date:yyMMdd}</Property>
```

The problem was 'upper:' and 'date:', with this change the name is replacing correctly :)